# How can I list all open (X11) windows on Gnu/Linux from a Python script?

Tags: python, user-interface, x11, xlib

I'd like to be able to grab a list of all windows that are open on a Linux desktop from a Python script. I suppose this would require working through Xlib or some other x11 or xdisplay library. This would be the Linux equivalent on win32's [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) API call.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use this to get a list of the title/caption text of every open window along with position/size information.

Is there some function call from Python that will return this info?

Comment: Python XLib https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib and [XQueryTree](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install `python-xlib`:

`pip3 install python-xlib`

Try this:

```
from Xlib import display

d = display.Display()
root = d.screen().root

query = root.query_tree()

for c in query.children:
    # returns window name or None
    name = c.get_wm_name()
    if name: 
        print(name)
```

I'm not sure about the other properties. `query.children` is a list of `Window` objects, so some research on those should turn up something.

`Window` object [docs](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/python-xlib_21.html#SEC20).

Comment: Why some windows are missing?

Comment: @Danil if you are using "Wayland" most of the packages can't get native windows.